# ViewPagerAndroid is not rendered under ScrollView using React-Native

Tags: android, android-viewpager, react-native

I can use ViewPagerAndroid, but when I put it under a ScrollView component nothing gets rendered. Did anyone encounter this before?

React-Native: version 0.22
Platform: Android

This works as expected:

```
<ViewPagerAndroid style={{flex: 1}} initialPage={0}>
     <View><Text>View 1</Text></View>
     <View><Text>View 2</Text></View>
     <View><Text>View 3</Text></View>
</ViewPagerAndroid>;
```

The following renders nothing:

```
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
<ViewPagerAndroid style={{flex: 1}} initialPage={0}>
     <View><Text>View 1</Text></View>
     <View><Text>View 2</Text></View>
     <View><Text>View 3</Text></View>
</ViewPagerAndroid>
</ScrollView>
```

I created an issue on github too:
[#6469](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6469)

Comment: Maybe you need to give the ScrollView a size too? Try putting something else in the ScrollView (like Text) to see if that renders fine.

Comment: @MartinKonicek When I give height to ViewPagerAndroid it started working as expected, but problem is I am trying to use flex: 1, so that scrollView will cover up as much as space there is available. Is there a way to achieve that, I updated the code by adding flex: 1 as style to ScrollView too.

Comment: I know it is an old question but can you try adding contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }} to your ScrollView. For example, <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>

Answer (score 9):

It is an old question but I also faced simmilar issue and solved it by adding contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }} to scrollview tag.
E.g.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ViewPagerAndroid style={{ flex: 1 }} initialPage={0}>
            <View><Text>View 1</Text></View>
            <View><Text>View 2</Text></View>
            <View><Text>View 3</Text></View>
        </ViewPagerAndroid>
    </ScrollView>
    {/*some other views*/}
    <View style={{ height: 20, width: null, flex: 1 }}/>
</View>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work for you.

```
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}} >
        <ViewPagerAndroid style={{flex: 1}} initialPage={0}>
           <View><Text>View 1</Text></View>
           <View><Text>View 2</Text></View>
           <View><Text>View 3</Text></View>
        </ViewPagerAndroid>
     </View>
</ScrollView>
```